# How to import the AwsClientBuilder class from the AWS Android SDK?

Tags: android, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to use AWS SQS in my android aplication.
I followed the instructions in this [official link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/how-to-android-sdk-setup.html) and couldn't run the sample codes from the documentation

### Codes added in the Gradle

```
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.6.+'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-sqs:2.6.+'
```

All the codes I found use **[AWSClientBuilder](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/client/builder/AwsClientBuilder.html)** to initialize an AWSClient object. This object it's responsible to use the other AWS' services

But, the AWSClientBuilder class is not available to me. There is no option to import any class from the package "com.amazonaws.client.builder". Also, I have not seen anywhere saying that this class has been depreciated.

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The AWSClientBuilder class is from the AWS Java SDK, which is different from the AWS Android SDK. That class does not exist on the AWS Android SDK.

You should be able to just use the [AmazonSQSClient](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sqs/AmazonSQSClient.html) class from the Android SDK.

Comment: Thanks so much, Viccari. It's worked for me with AmazonSQSClient(AWSCredentials awsCredentials) constructor.